# php file_put_contents can't create files on apache server directory

Tags: php, javascript

I have installed apache server on a linux fedora machine
and I put the following test.php and test.html on var/www/html
but when I open the 127.0.0.1/test.html on firefox
the test.php doesn't create the text.txt file, let alone write the string to the file
and the there is also no output for "echo $var"

the error is

```
Warning: file_put_contents(test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/getdata.php on line 7
```

the permission for the directory is:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Nov  6 14:14 html
```

test.php:

```
<?php
$v="x";
$fname='test.txt';
$rv=file_put_contents($fname,$v);
echo $rv;
echo $v;
?>
```

the test.html is so complex coz I planned to write something complex to a file on the server, but since there is some problem, I simplified the test.php

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="yourFormID" method="POST" action="/getdata.php" ></form>

<script>
  function sendArray( theArray )
  {
    var frm = document.getElementById('yourFormID');
    fld = document.createElement("INPUT");
    fld.name ="data"; 
    fld.type = "hidden";
    fld.value = JSON.stringify(theArray);
    frm.appendChild(fld);  
    frm.submit();
   }

   var yourArray = [0.000023323,0.00001292,0.00003323];

    sendArray( yourArray );

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Enable error reporting at the beginning of your test.php file to see what went wrong:


`error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`

Comment: it is the permission problem, I'm at a loss on how to deal with it

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP fopen() Error: failed to open stream: Permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665093/php-fopen-error-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html directory is currently owned by root, but under Fedora the web server runs as the "apache" user. (see "Apache File Security" section of https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Administration_Guide_Draft/Apache?rd=Docs/Drafts/AGBeta/Apache )

So, as root, do:

```
 chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/
 chmod -R 770 /var/www/html
```

The first makes the web server own the directory. The second makes sure that only users in the "apache" group can read/write files. It also says that no other users on the machine can even read them.

If you ever need another user to be able to write files into your web tree, add them to the "apache" group.

Comment: This is a good solution, however opening an entire web directory to the `apache` group & user is not a good practice from a high-security standpoint.

Comment: @MBJ Yes, if there are files/sub-directories which you keep under your /var/www/html directory tree but that you don't want to be servable by Apache, then change their ownership to myuser:myuser and permission to 700. If you have files/sub-directories you want to be read-only for Apache/PHP scripts, but writeable by another user, then change ownership to myuser:apache, and change permission to 750.  (But both those are fairly unusual use-cases, and deserve their own StackOverflow question :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is a permission problem with Linux. Try:

```
chmod 777 path/to/test.txt
```

at the command line.

**EDIT:** Here is a great article on Linux file permissions. http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html

**EDIT 2:**  I might add, setting the appropriate permissions for a file is the only way PHP can manipulate said file with `file_put_contents`, `fwrite`, etc.

Comment: just wondering if this is the case, then the server could be vulnerable?

Comment: No, the last 7 in the 777 is for `other`. This means any user within the server (local) can edit the specific file you grant such permissions to.