# fopen() Permission denied

Tags: php, permissions, fopen

I have an issue that I cannot create any files using fopen.

I am using this as a test:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("testfile.txt", "w")
?>
```

and this error is output in NewRelic (and no testfile.txt is not created):

> fopen(testfile.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP fopen() Error: failed to open stream: Permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665093/php-fopen-error-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied)

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov The duplicate question isn't the same issue I don't think, I am having issues on Linux a server not a local Mac. I'm not able to create the same solution.

Comment: Which user is running the php process? Does that user has permission to create a new file in that location/folder?

Comment: It is almost the same. The root of the problem is the same: insufficient privileges to write to the file, or to the directory  (the current directory, in particular). So check the permissions for both and fix them with `chmod`, e.g. `chmod 775 /path/to/the/directory && chmod 644 /path/to/the/directory/testfile.txt`. Undoubtedly, it's a FAQ.

Comment: @GoldenGonaz, look around, there are many links with the same question at the right column "Related". It doesn't matter Mac, or Linux. Both are Unix-like, and the permissions system is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you don't have the right to open it.
Make sure you have the right to write. If on linux you can use chmod() to set the the right of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the response @user7181041 the file testfile.txt doesn't exist though so I don't know how to set the permissions, I want to create it when I go to my php file (test.php). Only once it's created can I change permissions, but it won't create :)

Comment: if you want to create a file, make sure you have the x right